# Occurrences display in Solspace Calendar

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

I'm using the calendar:cal tag to display a list of upcoming events.

I'm having an issue where the first occurrence date displays as the next event date, rather than the next occurrence.

How can I code it so the event date is the next occurrence rather than the first event date?

```
{exp:calendar:cal date_range_start="today @ midnight" show_years="1" pad_short_weeks="n" event_limit="10" status="Open|Featured"}

    {if no_results}
        <p>There are no upcoming Events.</p>
    {/if}

    <div class="event">
        <div class="date">
            <span class="day">{event_first_date format="%j"}</span>
            <span class="month">{event_first_date format="%M"}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="summary">
            <h3><a href="{path="events/view/{categories}{category_url_title}{/categories}/{url_title}"}">{title}</a></h3>

        </div>
    </div>
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using {event_**start**_date} instead of {event_**first**_date}.

{event_**first**_date} will always be the date of the first occurrence of an event (i.e. the first date of your event), whereas {event_**start**_date}, when used in {exp:calendar:cal}, will be the start date of each occurrence.